# How to interpret a time varying probability in the context of failure rate analysis?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, random-variables

I am having trouble interpreting a time varying probability in the context of failure rate analysis.

For instance, suppose I define $X(t) \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\,\sigma^{2})$, a function $g(t)$ and then a time varying probability as $p(t) = P(X(t) < g(t))$. Now If I call the event $\{X(t) < g(t)\}$ the "failure" **that can only happen once**, what does the function $p(t) = P(X(t) < g(t))$ represent in this context?

EDIT 1: I am ultimately interested in the failure time distribution, which I suspect can be constructed out of the above function $p(t)$

Answer (score 1):

Since $g(t)$ is deterministic and the distribution of $X$ is known, $P\{X<g(t)\}$ is known at all instances $t$. The event you are looking for is the *waiting time* for the occurrence of $X<g(t)$. It follows an exponential distribution with a time varying rate of $\lambda(t)=P\{X<g(t)\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are confused about probability. $p(t) = \text{Pr}(X(t) < g(t))$ is the probability of failure with respect to time. And while it is true that it can only fail one time for one single object, the probability is realized over $\infty$ objects, or more realistically and practically, a finitely many number $N$ of objects, e.g. 100s or 1000s. Each object only fails once, but this probability density function of failure has to consider many objects.

Also, you don't need any simulation to verify this. You just have to straighten out the concept of probability.